# Using Chrome with out Gmail/Gsuite

Tags: google-chrome, office365

I have a scenario/question.  Our company has used GSuite for email, and it is not doing what we really need and we are looking to go to O365.  Here is the kicker, 98% of our users use Chrome with their work email account (ie gmail account), but if those are going away, how can we still use Chrome, with the saved passwords and all, without using the work gmail?  I tried setting up Chrome with an O365 account and no-go.

Comment: There is no requirement to log into any account just to use the Chrome browser. On the other hand, any saved passwords associated with the specific gmail account are simply not going to work with any other account (or without login), but it all depends how those passwords were saved.

Answer (score 0):

My company currently deploys Chromebooks for end-user workstations, and enforces Chrome as the primary web browser. We use the G Suite Admin tools provided by Google to pull account details from our Active Directory and create Google-friendly accounts using user's O365 email addresses, meaning Chrome recognizes "john.doe@domain.com" as a valid Google account. Essentially the users have a domain account, and a Google account that relies on the domain account for username and password info.

Unfortunately I don't know exactly how this is accomplished (above my pay grade), but if you're looking to integrate domain accounts/emails with Chrome or any Google product, [G Suite](https://gsuite.google.com/products/admin/) has worked for us for the past few years.